# jQuery Function Call issue

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I'm using magento 1.9 version.

I am creating custom module, which contains some javascript functions to be included.

I defined all javascript functions in seperate js file and included that js in my xml file under `app\design\mytheme\default`.

Called the js function in my phtml file. It shows the error : `(index):403 Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`. How to solve this.

Comment: can you attach XML and JS files here?

Comment: Sorry i cannot attch my whole XML and JS files due to my company principles.

Answer (score 0):

there can be several reasons of this issue:

1) Js file is not added to page (if something wrong in your XML)

2) Js file not added in Merged js file (so you can clean JS/Css cache at the bottom of Admin - System - Cache Management page)

3) Js file added, but it's code structure broken.

4) Js file added at the bottom of page, but function called before file insertion

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Neklo. The step 4 is caused my case. Because i called the function On document ready function. But i included the js as normal like `<action method="addJs"><script>mymodule/mymodule.js</script></action>`.

Comment: gimme vote up? ^.^

Comment: Is there any way to solve this.

Comment: if <action method="addJs"> code added to <reference name="head"> section - you need to clean JS/Css cache at the bottom of Admin - System - Cache Management page

Comment: and try to call your function like Event.observe(window, 'load', function() { myFunction(); });

Comment: I cleared cache and js is added in head already. Module is working fine in local But not in server.

Comment: cleaned all caches also? maybe it's under Layout cache. and if you have all js files merged into one - open that file and try to find your code

Comment: can you give server url to review?